# Songs that don't end with key chord?

Tags: chord-theory, key

I'm quite new to music theory, I think the fact that I've just found out that songs most of the time end with the key chords would prove it :D.

To be able to understand this better I'm looking for underlying theories why the music still can 'work' when this 'rule' isn't followed, preferable with examples from **regular songs** out there that don't end with their key chords? I would very much like to realize the differences :) thankyou

Comment: There are many arrangements for big bands that end on seemingly strange chords which appear to have little or nothing to do with the key that's been played in for the rest of the tune.

Comment: Examples from last gig - All of Me (Bb), ending on Eb13(#11). All Blues (Bb), ending on F9(#11). Kansas City (Bb) ending on E7#9, but this is comment only as it's probably not exactly what you require.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some pieces that don't end in the key they start in:

- Every song that uses the "truck driver's gear change" at least once to push the key up at least one semitone (Livin' on a Prayer, That's the Way It Is, You Raise Me Up, etc.)
- A lot of ragtime (Elite Syncopations, Reflection Rag, Frog Legs Rag, etc.--ragtime pieces commonly end in the subdominant key)
- A lot of marches (The Stars and Stripes Forever, Manhattan Beach March, Entry of the Gladiators, etc.--marches commonly end in the subdominant key)
- Chopin's Scherzo No. 2 in B Flat Minor (ends in D flat major)
- Blue Rondo a la Turk (starts in F major, ends in A major/minor)
- The 7th movement of Schumann's Kreisleriana (starts in C minor, ends in E flat major)

The second movement of Beethoven's Appassionata Sonata ends with a diminished 7th chord, but it goes to the third movement without a break, so I'm not sure how much that counts.

Comment: Correct, but not I think the useful answer to this question.   I think it's about songs that don't end on the tonic of the key that has been established IN THAT SECTION of the piece.   Ragtime and marches (very similar forms btw) end on a conventional tonic chord of that section.    It's also possible to 'just leave it hanging'. Or the pretty version of an interrupted cadence that ends on VI(maj7). An example is 'Day by day' from 'Godspell'.